# Java 8 Function Style Programming what is the difference between currying and Functions Composition

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, currying

I am pretty new to the world of functional programming.Trying the new function style programming that ships with Java 8. recently I have come to know about currying and method composition. Understanding the true essence of functional style programming using java is pretty hard and now I have a couple of questions, However, before asking all these questions I have tried the same on python and now a bit familiar with few core concepts.

1.In java how Currying and method composition are different In fact I don't see any difference at all, especially after reading this article https://dzone.com/articles/higher-order-functions

2.As a programmar (from my java programming perspective) why would I prefer currying. for example why would i Do this 
`f(x){ return g(y) }` instead of `f(x,y){ return x(y)}` what difference does it make?

Comment: Java 8 only has a small subset of what functional programming usually allows for, so it may be hard to see the benefits.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and in general? without thinking of java what would be the answer to my second question. I really want to know

Comment: That article is wrong. As @Holger pointed out in the [accepted answer's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398362/java-8-function-style-programming-what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-fu#comment77792940_45401296), what the author of the article calls *currying* is in fact *partial function application*, or you can also say that he's *binding* either the first or the second argument.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I got your point and now I am more confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While both operations output a function, the example makes the difference fairly clear:

1. Currying takes a single function `f()` and produces an "intermediate" function `f'()` that is the same as `f()` but with some parameters already fixed. When you eventually fill in the rest of the parameters, you will evaluate the original `f()`.
2. Whereas composition will take two functions `f()` and `g()` and creates a completely different function `g(f())`.

Take a simple example: `f(x,y) = x+y`, where `x` and `y` are integers. No amount and combination of currying of this function can result in a function that will ever return a non-integer result. But compose it with `g(x) = x/2`, and you get `g(f(x,y)) = (x+y)/2`, which will of course happily return non-integers.

Why would you then use currying?

Java instance methods for example are a result of a fairly similar process. Instance methods differ from static methods in that they've got an extra hidden parameter called `this`. When you say `new Foo()`, essentially you bind this hidden parameter to the newly created `Foo` object. So instead of having to call function `void bar(Foo this, int x)`, you can just refer to it as `void bar(int x)`, with the first parameter already fixed in place. (By the way, `void bar(Foo this, int x)` is in fact perfectly valid Java syntax, we just almost never use it.)

This isn't entirely a coincidence, as pure functional languages can only have functions whose outputs depend on its inputs alone (as opposed to OO languages, where the output of a method can also depend on the internal state of the object the method belongs to.)

As a general advice, if you want to learn the essence of functional programming, it's best not to do it from Java. Not even from Scala either. Try to learn it from a pure functional language like Haskell and then you can come back to Java and understand much better what subset of FP was implemented in it and how.

Comment: that was great, now I understand the difference between functional style and purely functional programming.

Comment: *Currying* converts `(a,b) -> a + b` to `a -> b -> a + b`.  At this time, no argument has been fixed yet. Only when you apply a value to the outer function, the returned function has a fixed value for `a`. This is called *partial function application*.

Comment: You are correct, the example does both in one step.

Answer (score 7):

I d like to add some code to very nice explanation by @biziclop:

Example of currying in functional Java  :

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, IntFunction<Integer>> currying = (x, y) -> z -> x * y / z;
    System.out.println(currying.apply(5, 6).apply(2)); // 15
```

As you can see lambda is parameterized. In this example, we are currying to multiply 5 by 6, and then dividing by 2.

First `apply(5)` invoked and variable `x` gets value `5` and function becomes `5 * y / z`

Then `apply(6)` invoked and variable 'y' gets value '6' and function becomes `5 * 6 / z`

Then `apply(2)` invoked and variable 'z' gets value '2' and function becomes `5 * 6 / 2`

As you can use currying this way is of little use in Java. 
Currying is useful in pure functional languages, where functions are limited to a single-argument and they benefit from currying, which transforms function that takes multiple arguments, so it can be called multiple times each with single argument invocations.

So how can you benefit from currying in Java?

It is useful when you need to parameterize function at multiple levels. For example, let's say we have several collections, each representing different category and we want to retrieve particular elements from each category. Below is simple example, given two collections, representing spelled numbers, categorized as `ones` and `tens`. 
Example :

```
public class Currying {

    private static List<String> ones = 
           Arrays.asList("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", 
                                 "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine");
    private static List<String> tens =
           Arrays.asList("Zero", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty",
                                "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety");

    public static Function<String, Function<Integer, String>> getNumbers() {
        return units -> number -> {
                        return units == "Ones" ? ones.get(number % 10) 
                                               : tens.get(number % 10);
                                  };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<String, Function<Integer, String>> currying = getNumbers();
        System.out.println(currying.apply("Tens").apply(8)); // 80
        System.out.println(currying.apply("Ones").apply(2)); // 2
    }

}
```

In above example function `currying` returns another function
    `currying.apply("Ones").apply(2))`;

First `apply("Tens")` is invoked and variable `units` becomes `Tens`

Then `apply(2)` is invoked and variable `number` becomes `8` retrieving `80` from `tens` collection.

Same logic applies to `currying.apply("Ones").apply(2))`.

Comment: Beautiful example. Thanks a ton.

Comment: And `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, IntFunction<Integer>>` is a very good example of why this is rather tedious to do in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Currying is a way to create new functions by "baking in" arguments to existing functions.  This is typically done in languages like Haskell where the language syntax leans itself towards doing it easily.

A typical example is to have a function `(addTwoNumbers a b)` which adds two numbers where currying is to supply *less* arguments to get a function that takes the remaining arguments to do things.   For instance `(addTwoNumbers 42)` where a is provided (42) but not b, is a function (not a result) that takes *one* argument (b) and returns 42+b.  So `((addTwoNumbers 42) 10)` would return 52.

As you can see the language syntax must help for this to work well, and Java doesn't help much which is why it doesn't show up much in tutorials.  The functional aspects in Java 8 is mostly to avoid for-loops in code using Streams and to have a reasonable amount of predefined Functions to use as scaffolding with lambda expressions.   They have lazy evaluation in Streams which is very nice and a great achievement, but does not buy the programmer a lot in terms of expressiveness in code.

See https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying for a more technical explanation.